# Lightning component: highlighting wrong element on hover

Tags: lightning-aura-components, css

I have a progress bar component, split into 5 segments. For some reason, when I hover on a segment, the next segment is highlighted instead of the current segment. You can't see my cursor, but it's hovering on the 2nd checkmark:

[image: progbar]

component:

```
    <a class="slds-path__link" href="javascript:void(0);" role="tab" onclick="{!c.onSelect}" title="{!v.value.name}">
    <!--slds-path__link: scrunches bars up vertically-->

        <span class="slds-path__title">
            <!--slds-path__title: text color-->
            <aura:if isTrue="{!v.value.status == 'complete'}">
                <lightning:icon iconName="utility:check" size="xx-small" variant="inverse" class="path-indicator slds-m-right_x-small" alternativeText=""/>
            </aura:if>
            <aura:if isTrue="{!v.value.status == 'current'}">
                <lightning:icon iconName="utility:trail" size="xx-small" variant="inverse" class="path-indicator slds-m-right_x-small" alternativeText=""/>
            </aura:if>

            <!-- Don't show the label when milestones are complete -->
            <ui:outputText class="{!'label-' + v.value.status}" value="{!v.value.name}"/> <!--removes text-->

        </span>
    </a>
</li>
```

css:

```
.THIS.slds-is-active .label-complete {
    display: inline;
}

.THIS .label-complete {
display: none;
}

/* Prevent random ellipsis when the screen is zoomed in */
.THIS.slds-is-complete:not(.slds-is-active) .slds-path__title { /*not = everything other than the specified element*/
    text-overflow: clip;
}
```

Comment: Any reason why you're not using `lightning:progressIndicator` for this?

Comment: We thought about that but there's a few few features we have in our version that are not in lightning:progressIndicator